# SwiftUI Allowing a button to only be tapped once

Tags: button, swiftui

I have a button that increments a firebase value by one, however I'm trying to only allow that button to be tapped once. Tried a few things but couldn't get it work correctly is there an simple way to get this working?

```
Button(action: {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let like = Int.init(self.likes)!
    db.collection("posts").document(self.id).updateData(["likes": "\(like + 1)"]) { err in
        if err != nil {
            print(err)
            return
        }

        print("updated...")
    }
}) {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.up.square")
        .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple demo:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonTapped = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.buttonTapped.toggle()
            // other actions...
        }) {
            Text("Tap me")
        }
        .disabled(buttonTapped)
    }
}
```